# cmd line doesn't recognise adb.. even i am not ble to change the directory

Tags: batch-file, adb

this is what i am getting

```
C:\>cd e:>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\>cd E:
E:\

C:\>
```

if i say cd e: and enter it gives these two lines as i press enter

```
E:\

C:\>
```

here in e drive i have my android sdk from where i have to access the adt..

there is another way of accessing adb by setting adb as envoirnment var. i have also done that

clicked on my computer/properties/advance/envoirnment variables/new 
i set name as adb and value is `E:\Amit_Software's\android-sdk_r18-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools`

still it doesn't recognise adb..

i will realy appreciate if any one can help me out

thanks in adavance

Comment: -1 for a poorly written question

Comment: Thanks Adarshr, i am not that good in english that is the reason

Answer (score 0):

You can change directory to another drive on the command line using `cd /d` like this:

`cd /d E:`